# 553 5.7.1 [BL21] Connections will not be accepted from IP

Tags: spam, email-spam

I trying to send mails from SMTP server to yahoo but not sending mails and getting below error.
553 5.7.1 [BL21] Connections will not be accepted from IP, because the ip is in Spamhaus's list; see http://postmaster.yahoo.com/550-bl23.html

Is there any chance to remove IP from PBL?

Comment: I am facing the same error while sending mail to yahoo from SMTP. Did you find any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to know is: the PBL is not a blacklist.

> You are not listed for spamming or for anything you have done. The PBL is simply a list of all of the world's dynamic IP space, i.e: IP ranges normally assigned to ISP broadband customers (DSL, DHCP, PPP, cable, dialup). It is perfectly normal for dynamic IP addresses to be listed on the PBL. In fact all dynamic IP addresses in the world should be on the PBL. Even static IPs which do not send mail should be listed in the PBL. (from http://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/Spamhaus%20PBL#183)

This is also confirmed on the site you've mentioned  http://postmaster.yahoo.com/550-bl23.html :

> In our continuing efforts to protect our users from unsolicited email, Yahoo Mail doesn't accept SMTP connections from:
>
> - Dynamic or residential IP addresses as determined by Spamhaus PBL

Have you turned on 'SMTP AUTHENTICATION'? That might could help, regarding Spamhaus, but it certainly depends more on Yahoos configuration.